How do I fix this error when I start my updates?
Here is the error:
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/dismine/valentina/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
I get these all the time. I have this same kind of error on different devices for different apps.This one is from valentina but I also get one for brave browser on another computer. Is there a way to make it stop? It shows up using discover and using the konsole.
What I don't understand is I get this error and the program works perfect.
Any help would be awesome thank you.

A quick look at https://launchpad.net/~dismine/+archive/ubuntu/valentina  (taken from your question) shows support stopped in 2021; so why would you expect support for the 2024-April release??  PPAs are 3rd party sources, so the only security checks are those you perform yourself, adding a repository that is no longer maintained I'd consider a potential risk, and given it provides no support for your release - I wonder why you added it?

Okay. I did not know any of this. I have used Ubuntu for a few years now and I have never had this happen before. I appreciate your help. I will just deal for now. I am trying to switch to inkscape. I really just thought I did something wrong. I didn't want to break something important. Thank you.
